# How to open rar file in java 1.4

Tags: java

I guess ZipFile doesn't supprort rar file. What lib is better to use to unrar rar files and unzip zip files in java 1.4

Comment: I just realized that you asked for java 1.4. Why would anyone still use java 1.4???

Comment: Because he have a lot of versions of out product that are about 10 years old :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest [Raroscope](http://www.adarshr.com/papers/raroscope) but it only allows scanning of the file. I suspect the best option is to execute `rar.exe` from your Java program.

Answer (score 2):

Junrar adds support to read and extract a rar.

It came from an old sourceforge-host port of the unrar library that is no longer available and went to github on
https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar

The newest version is available in
https://github.com/junrar/junrar/
and can be included as dependency in maven as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.junrar</groupId>
  <artifactId>junrar</artifactId>
  <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

it is a good option

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be a lot out there. Take a look at this library:

http://www.unrarlib.org/

Comment: Here's the link to the java library they recommend: http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/jlrarx.html#rarlib (but it's just a source assembly that you can compile yourself)

Answer (score 0):

For Zip files I'd use [Apache Commons / Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/)

Rar Files are a lot harder. There's almost nothing I could find, except a [sample source file](http://code.google.com/p/jdvdkat/source/browse/trunk/JDvdKat/src/com/rosamez/dirlistex/RarReader.java) in the Google Code project JDVKat which uses a library called  de.innosystec.unrar that's supposedly "a piece of shit" (sorry, but that's what it reads). (You can also [download the library](http://jdvdkat.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JDvdKat/lib/java-unrar-0.3.jar) there)

Comment: here are links to the library they use: https://github.com/jukka/java-unrar and https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar